# Get related posts from tag otherwise from category (Ajax Load More plugin)

Tags: wp-query

*Old title: Get Related Posts by Tag if Tag is Empty Get Posts by Category*

I'm using Ajax Load More, and I'm trying to get related posts by tag. Which works:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID); // get current categories
$term_array = []; // Create empty category array

foreach( $terms as $term ) { // Loop founf categories
  $term_array[] = $term->slug;
}

echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more tag="'. implode(",", $term_array) .'" post__not_in="' . $post->ID . '" post_type="post" posts_per_page="3" scroll="false" progress_bar="true" progress_bar_color="blue" images_loaded="true" button_label="Load More" css_classes="related-posts-container" button_loading_label="Loading More" container_type="div" ]');
```

But when I try to implement a feature where I get posts by category when that tag is empty it crashes on me. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
function getRelatedPostsByTag(){
// Related Posts
$terms = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID); // get current categories
$term_array = []; // Create empty category array

foreach( $terms as $term ) { // Loop founf categories
  $term_array[] = $term->slug;
}

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'post__not_in'  => $post->ID,
    'tag'               => implode(",", $term_array),
    'post_type'         => 'post'
);
$related_posts = get_posts( $args );

$query = 'tag="'. implode(",", $term_array) .'"';

if (count($related_posts) > 1) {
return $query;
}
else {
wp_reset_postdata();
getRelatedPostsByCategory();
}
}

function getRelatedPostsByCategory(){

$categories = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
$categories_array = [];

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $categories_array[] = $category->CatSlug;
}
$query = 'category="'. implode(",", $categories_array) .'"';

return $query;
}

wp_reset_postdata();

echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more '. getRelatedPostsByTag() .' post__not_in="' . $post->ID . '" post_type="post" posts_per_page="3" scroll="false" progress_bar="true" progress_bar_color="blue" images_loaded="true" button_label="Load More" css_classes="related-posts-container" button_loading_label="Loading More" container_type="div" ]');
```

Comment: In your second dump `$post->ID` is always undefined. No wonder it's breaking. Are you missing `global $post`? Or are you functions missing a `$post` or `$post_id` parameter? Or where is that post ID supposed to come from?

Comment: It's a global post, it should be getting it by default when it's run. I have this code in my single.php file.

Comment: Make the post or preferable just the post ID a parameter of your functions and then pass it in there. `function getRelatedPostsByTag($post_id)` and then use `$post_id` inside the function for the subsequent stuff going on with it.

Comment: @leymannx doesn't look like it's working for me, unless I'm doing something wrong again. https://www.pastiebin.com/5cae669dc94da

Comment: Uh, there are multiple occurrences of `$object - > property;` which you should fix to `$object->property`. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php. My advise is to get PHPStorm ASAP. It will point you immediately to those culprits. It's definitely worth its money.

Answer (score 0):

I was calling the category id instead of the category name.

Here's the code that by default tries using tags to bring in relevant posts, and if there are no posts by tags it'll bring in posts using the same category. This code work in the single.php using the Ajax Load More wordpress plugin.

```
// Related Posts by tag
$terms = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID); // get current categories
$term_array = []; // Create empty category array

foreach( $terms as $term ) { // Loop founf categories
$term_array[] = $term->slug;
}
$query = '';

$args = array(
'posts_per_page'    => 1,
'post__not_in'  => $post->ID ,
'tag'               => implode(",", $term_array),
'post_type'         => 'post'
);
$related_posts = get_posts( $args );
if ($related_posts) { // Tags

$query = ' tag="'. implode(",", $term_array) .'"';

} else {

$categories = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);

if($categories){
$categories_array = [];
foreach ($categories as $category) {
$cat = get_term( $category );
$categories_array[] = $cat->slug;
}
if(!empty($categories_array)){
$query = ' category="'. implode(",", $categories_array) .'"';
}
}

}

echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more'. $query .' post__not_in="' . $post->ID . '" post_type="post" posts_per_page="3" scroll="false" progress_bar="true" progress_bar_color="blue" images_loaded="true" button_label="Load More" css_classes="related-posts-container" button_loading_label="Loading More" container_type="div" ]');
```